# Como faço para um objeto voltar para sua posição inicial no Unity?

Tags: unity3d

Tenho um objeto que é atingido pelo raycast e uso 
 `cObj.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(cObj.transform.position,main.transform.position, step);`
para o objeto ir de encontro com a câmera.

Como faço para ele voltar para a sua posição inicial?
Tenho um botão que ao ser focalizado a imagem volta de onde veio.

Comment: Esse objecto que e atinjido por um raycast a posicao inicial dele e sempre a mesma ?

Answer (score 1):

Olha eu armazenaria a posição inicial em uma variável e quando for atingido carregava o `transform position` setando os valores que foram setados na variável.

Talvez tenha uma forma mais prática, mas eu faria assim

Comment: Eu tentei isso, mas ele não volta para a posição antes de se mover para a frente

Comment: Pode mostrar mais código, para avaliarmos melhor o problema?

Answer (score 1):

Eu criava um variável com a posicao inicial entre a câmara e o objecto que pretende mover e depois para retornar à posição original faria:

```
var posicao_inicial =  new Vector3(3,3,3);


cObj.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(cObj.transform.position, main.transform.position-Vector3.Distance(cObject.position, posicao_inicial), step);
```

Não trabalho com o Unity há algum tempo, nem tenho como testar aqui, mas penso que algo dentro do gênero funcionará.

Answer (score 0):

Julia, crie uma variável ex. *Vector3 posicaoInicial*, para guardar a posição, em seguida no metodo Start coloque *posicaoInicial = transform.position;*

Dai quando você quiser que ele volte para a posição inicial dele você usa: *transform.position = posicaoInicial;*

Answer (score -2):

Eu fiz assim;

No game utilizei um botão para mudar a posição

```
public class ResetaPosicao : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject carro;
    private Vector3 nvposicao;


public void nvlocal()
{
Vector3 nvposition = new Vector3 (0.16f,2.43f,-28.72f); 
        carro.transform.position = nvposicao;
}

}
```